# PanicException: env_logger::init_from_env should not be called after logger initialized: SetLoggerError(())

Tags: python, exception, panic

When I try to run a line of code:

**from transformers import pipeline**

I am getting the panicException as follow as:

PanicException: env_logger::init_from_env should not be called after logger initialized: SetLoggerError(()) in Python

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this is a Rust module that's packaged with python. It uses `env_logger`, which needs to be set *before* the logger is created in Python. That's why this happened. It looks like a a bug in the library itself.